# Semantic issue in Api Blueprint complaining about ignoring additional response header

Tags: apiblueprint

Creating an API Blueprint at [Apiary](http://apiary.io/), I am running into an error in my blueprint markdown that is being flagged as a semantic issue with the message:

> Line 21 - Ignoring additional response header(s), specify this header(s) in the referenced model definition instead.

Line 21 is the line that references the [Cars][] model definition.  I am not trying to specify any headers and I am confused by what this message is trying to instruct me to do.  Can anyone shed some light on the problem?

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Automative Industry

# Group Cars

## Cars [/cars]

+ Model (application/json)

    + Body

            {
              "name": "Taurus"
            }

### List all cars [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    [Cars][]

+ Response 401

+ Response 403

+ Response 500

+ Response 503
```

Answer (score 3):

Gordon, you defined `(application/json)` twice. Just remove it in the response:

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Automative Industry

# Group Cars

## Cars [/cars]

+ Model (application/json)

    + Body

            {
              "name": "Taurus"
            }

### List all cars [GET]

+ Response 200

    [Cars][]

+ Response 401

+ Response 403

+ Response 500

+ Response 503
```